# How to enable Single App Mode on iPad when configurator fails?

Tags: ios, ipad, mdm, kiosk, apple-configurator

I'm trying to enable Single App Mode on an iPad. I'm using Apple Configurator 2 to set the iPad to this mode.

I'm getting an error and I don't get it enabled for some reasons I cannot find on Google. Anyone with an idea?

```
The profile must be installed using a device management tool.     
[MCInstallationErrorDomain – 0xFB5 (4021)]
```

[image]